# ASP.NET/JavaScript: Remove all cookies

Tags: asp.net, javascript, cookies

How can I remove all my site's cookies from the client, either in ASP.NET/C# or JavaScript? Basically I would like to click a button or link on the page and have it clear all the cookies for the site. I don't need to know the name of every cookie, do I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I wrote before to @mwilson, you cannot directly delete a cookie on a user's computer. However, you can direct the user's browser to delete the cookie by setting the cookie's expiration date to a past date.

To delete all cookies just browse the Response.Cookies collection with a foreach loop and replace the date of each cookie with a past date.

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195.aspx) page if you need some help:

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach (string key in Request.Cookies.AllKeys)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(key);
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```